# How to get JComboBox item's screen coordinates

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to get the screen coordinates (x,y) of items in a `JComboBox`. Preferably I would like the entire bounding box (x,y, width,height), but mostly the position.

This information has many uses. Click automation, checking what might be obscured by the list (or what might obscure the list), testing proximity to edge of display or other possibly undesirable locations, etc..

I am getting the coordinates of normal components (`Component`) simply by using `Component.getLocationOnScreen`. Sometimes I want the center point, for which I take the x/y of `getLocationOnScreen` and just add half the `getWidth` or `getHeight`.

How can I do something similar for the visual real estate of the drop-down items under the combo box?

[image: JComboBox dropped down]

In the above picture, for example, I would like to get the x,y coordinates of "Test 1" (in the drop-down, not in the editor), or of "Test 2" or "Test 3".

That is, if "Test 1" is at (10,10), "Test 2" at (10,20), "Test 3" at (10,30), and each has (width,height) of (30,10), I want `f(0) = (10,10)`, `f(1) = (10,20)`, `f(2) = (10,30)`. Or, if we do get the full bounds as well, then `f(2) = (10,20,30,10)`, but again, the full bounds is secondary to getting at least the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do something similar for the visual real estate of the drop-down items under the combo box?

You can access the JList that is used to display the items of the combo box.

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(...);
BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
JList list = popup.getList();
Rectangle bounds = list.getCellBounds(...);
// bounds will be relative to the bottom of the combo box.
```

I've only used logic like the above in a listener, so I'm not sure if the popup is created when the combobox is first created or when the popup is displayed for the first time.

Comment: Fortunately for me at this moment, I am not fetching the data until after the popup is displayed anyway, so this works great for me. If I ever need it before that and it becomes a problem, I suppose that will be another, narrower question for another day. Thank you.